# Creating Horizontal and Vertical lines with varying axes values? (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I am trying to plot both horizontal and vertical lines on a histogram that will be accurate to changing limits on both the x and y axes. I was using the line(X,Y) function, but cannot find a useful way to get the lines to be set depending on the parameters of the graph window.

Comment: have you tried manipulating the grid of the plot?

Comment: No, but I don't think that will help. I need to make a vertical and horizontal line that will plot at a specific point with regards to the changing limits of the x and y axis. I also need a way to plot a line at some specific variable that is not an X,Y coordinate, but rather a single numerical value, and plots a  horizontal line through that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you want but here's the simplest answer to what I think you want:

Makes a sample histogram

```
y = randn(100,1);
hist(y,10)
```

Get the current limits of the x and y axes

```
xlimits = get(gca, 'XLim');
ylimits = get(gca, 'YLim');
```

Computes a single numeric value to plot a horizontal line.You'll want to replace this with your specific function of the axes limits

```
halfpt = ((ylimits(2)-ylimits(1))/2) + ylimits(1);
line(xlimits, [halfpt halfpt])
```

I'm not sure, but from your comment I'm suspecting that you aren't changing your axes programmatically, with say `set(gca,'Xlim', [0 10])` but that you want to be able to drag the axes of your your figure with the mouse, say by using that hand/pointer button in the figure editor. In which case, one solution is to make your figure a  GUI and write a callback function that handles line plotting that is a function of the `xlim` and `ylim`. Here's an example that always keeps the line in the middle of the axes regardless of how they are dragged:

```
function myGUI
figure('WindowButtonMotionFcn',@myCallback)
y = randn(100,1);
hist(y,10)

function myCallback(src,eventdata)
xlimits = get(gca, 'XLim');
ylimits = get(gca, 'YLim');
halfpt = ((ylimits(2)-ylimits(1))/2) + ylimits(1);

lh = findall(gcf,'Type','Line');
delete(lh);
myline = line(xlimits, [halfpt halfpt])

end

end
```